Intuition behind unit roots in practice
One area where the application of unit roots to time series modelling seems very intuitive is in climate change: carbon dioxide stays in the air, so past shocks (size of flow) have a cumulative effect on the size of the stock and don't die away over time.
On the other hand, it also seems intuitive that stock market prices should be modelled as unit roots under EMH since this implies that the best predictor of a future realisation of the underlying DGP is its realisation today.
Both are reasons why we would use unit roots. Can we somehow link the rationales behind them? For example, is there any way of fitting the persistent shocks/stock-flow explanation to stock markets?
